# Issues installing Node via homebrew

Tags: node.js, macos, terminal, homebrew

I'm attempting to get the LTS version of node installed on my machine via homebrew but I seem to be having some issues. If I run `brew install node@6` to get the latest LTS version (6.10.3), everything seems to complete with no issues. Then, if I run `brew list`, I will see `node@6` has indeed installed. BUT, if I check which version of node is installed using `node -v`, I receive `zsh: command not found: node`. I'm pretty new to homebrew and the command line in general. Where have I gone wrong?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and I can provide more info if requested. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For those curious, I ended up just using `brew install node` to install the most current version of node. Trying to install `node@6` was troublesome, but it seems my struggle was pertaining to an issue where homebrew required `node@6` to be linked using `brew link node@6 --force`. More info can be found here:

https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/2220

Note that I did not try this solution.

Answer (score 2):

As indicated in the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/2220) linked above, if you run `brew info node@10` (replace `node@10` with your version) it provides a line to add the non-latest node version to your path:

> If you need to have node@10 first in your PATH run: 
>     `echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/node@10/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc`

Running `echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/node@10/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc` adds a line to the bottom of my `.zshrc` file:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/node@10/bin:$PATH"
```

If you're using Bash, it'd be your `.bashrc` file. I'm guessing Homebrew picks up on that, but worth double checking.

This line will add `/usr/local/opt/node@10/bin` to my PATH when I start my terminal. I need to restart my terminal to get immediate access. Or I can re-source the `.zshrc` file. I only have to do this the first time:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Now `node` works. I can verify by checking the version:

```
node -v
# v10.17.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you check if `/usr/local/bin` is in your `$PATH`? Also, maybe run `brew doctor`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tuan! If I echo my `$PATH`, the output is:

`/Users/<username>/.npm-packages/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`. Could this be the issue? Not very familiary with `$PATH`. I could have easily mucked this up during this process.

Edit: Seems that `/usr/local/bin` exists in my path based on the output.

Comment: `node not found` :(

Comment: `usr/local/bin` is already in PATH, maybe try sourcing it again or quit and start your terminal again.

Comment: what's really strange to me is that if i run `brew install node` instead of `brew install node@6`, everything works fine. node installs, and if i check the version i get `v7.10.0`.

Comment: I used `n` to manage node version. Never bother homebrew with this. Maybe you can check it out. https://github.com/tj/n Very easy to switch between node version.